# How to localize timeline component from primefaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2

I want to use a timeline component from the Primefaces

```
<p:timeline id="timeline" value="#{dashboardBean.model}" height="250px"
                                    locale="cs_CZ"
     ...

</p:timeline>
```

I have defined a locale in JS which work correctly for a Calendar component. Nevertheless I am not able to make it work for the timeline.

```
PrimeFaces.locales ['cs_CZ'] = {
    closeText: 'Zavřít',
    prevText: 'Předchozí',
    nextText: 'Následující',
...
};
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out. TimeLine is based on [chap links library](https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library/tree/master/js/src/timeline).
You need to create a javascript code which looks like this:

```
if (typeof links === 'undefined') {
    links = {};
    links.locales = {};
} else if (typeof links.locales === 'undefined') {
    links.locales = {};
}

links.locales['cz'] = {
    'MONTHS': ["Leden", "Únor", "Březen", "Duben", "Květen", "Červen", "Červenec", "Srpen", "Zaří", "Říjen", "Listopad", "Prosinec"],
    'MONTHS_SHORT': ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"],
    'DAYS': ["Neděle", "Pondělí", "Úterý", "Středa", "Čtvrtek", "Pátek", "Sobota"],
    'DAYS_SHORT': ["Ne", "Po", "Út", "St", "Čt", "Pá", "So"],
    'ZOOM_IN': "Přiblížit",
    'ZOOM_OUT': "Oddálit",
    'MOVE_LEFT': "Doleva",
    'MOVE_RIGHT': "Doprava",
    'NEW': "Nový",
    'CREATE_NEW_EVENT': "Vytvořit novou akci"
};
```

**In jsf:**

```
 <p:timeline id="timeline" value="#{dashboardBean.model}" height="250px"
                                        locale="cz"
         ...

    </p:timeline>
```